# Load edit template of kendogrid on click of edit button like detail template

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I need to load the edit template on click of the Edit button in Kendo Grid just below the row that is edited.
Currently detail template is shown as edit template in the fiddle.

```
function detailInit(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    var detailRow = dataItem.detailRow;
    var model = e.data; //keep reference to the model

    detailRow.find(".tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
        animation: {
            open: { effects: "fadeIn" }
        }
    });

    detailRow.find(".user-details > input[type='button']").click(function() {
        var ds = $(this).closest(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
        //retrieve the input values
        var UserDescriptionValue = detailRow.find(".user-details>input[name=UserDescription]").val();
        var NumberValue = detailRow.find(".user-details>input[name=Number]").val();
        var CodeValue = detailRow.find(".user-details>input[name=Code]").val();
        var PartitionValue = detailRow.find(".user-details>input[name=Partition]").val();
        //use set method to change the corresponding values of the model
        //in that way the record will be marked as dirty
        model.set("UserDescription", UserDescriptionValue);
        model.set("Number", NumberValue );
        model.set("Code", CodeValue );
        model.set("Partition", PartitionValue );        
    });
}
```

Please refer the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z26U3/16/

Comment: You need to tell your "edit" command what to do when it gets clicked: `command:[
    {name:"edit", click: detailInit, text:""},
{name:"destroy", text:""}`. After that, you will find a problem with `var model = e.data`, but I'm not quite sure what you are doing there. So you will have to play around with that to get it right. But, `dataItem` looks like it was correct to me, but `detailRow` came back undefined.

Comment: See the Kendo documentation on custom commands for more information: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/custom-command.html

Comment: I've added expand Row functionality on click of Custom Command button(Edit). Updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z26U3/18/

Comment: Looks like that's working for you. Did you have any other issues with it?

Comment: Yes, few issues are there. On add button click, I need the same EditUserTemplate to come above the grid and below the AddUser button.
Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z26U3/23/

Answer (score 0):

So, to summarize, in order for your row Custom command buttons to execute, you need to tell them what has to be done via the "click" property on each command.

In order for toolbars to work, you have to hook those up to javascript functions. Since you want the addUser inputs to show up right under the add button, I moved all the toolbar specifications out into a template, that allows you to easily hook everything up with javascript.

Here is the [fiddle with the updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/Z26U3/47/).

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <input type="button" class="k-button" id="addUser" onClick="addUser()" value="Add User" />
    </div>
    <div id="addNewUser" style="display:none">
        User Description: <input id="newUserName" type="text" name="UserDescription"/><br />
        Number: <input id="newUserNumber" type="text" name="Number"/><br />
        Code: <input id="newUserCode" type="text" name="Code"/><br />
        Partition: <input id="newUserPartition" type="text" name="Partition"/><br />
        <input type="button" id='saveNewUser' class="k-button" onClick="saveUser()" value="Save" /><input type="button" id='cancelAddUser' class="k-button" onClick="cancelAddUser()" value="Cancel" />
    </div>
</script>
```

Then, in your javascript, you need to add functions to handle everything:

```
function addUser(){
    $("#addNewUser").toggle();
}
function saveUser(){
    alert("place code to save user here");
    //Get the input valies from your addUserForm.
    var name = $("#newUserName").val();
    var number = $("#newUserNumber").val();
    var code = $("#newUserCode").val();
    var partition = $("#newUserPartition").val();
}
function cancelAddUser()
{
    $("#newUserName").val("");
    $("#newUserNumber").val("");
    $("#newUserCode").val("");
    $("#newUserPartition").val("");
    $("#addNewUser").toggle();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joe for your help. This is working awesome. Only problem I'm facing here is the dropdownlist is not loading in the kendo template.
Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z26U3/53/

Comment: I've got the solution. After referring to this site:http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/DropDownList.html The updated fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z26U3/57/

Comment: For the column ZWave lock control, Checkbox is not binding in the detail template. Also dropdown is not loading for Authority column, whereas its loading in addtemplate. Can you please help me out in this? Thanks for your time. Below is the updated fiddle: jsfiddle.net/Z26U3/63

Comment: You need to reference Authority from within the detail row as `${Authority}`. I'll take a look about getting the KendoDropDown to work in the detail row after a bit. http://jsfiddle.net/Z26U3/71/

Comment: Based on this example: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/detailtemplate.html, you need to add a function for `detailInit`, and assign it in your grid configuration right below your detailTemplate assignment: `detailInit: detailInit`. In your detailInit function, you then need to use jquery to create your kendo dropdown for your Authority. If you follow the example, it should be pretty straightforward from there.

Comment: I added the code for loading the dropdown in detailInit function, still its not loading. http://jsfiddle.net/Z26U3/74/
But I'm wondering already the following html structure exists in detail template for loading the dropdownlist, where data: Authority refers to the userViewModel. Really confused. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post an updated Fiddle for me to see what you have done?

Comment: Alright, I have updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z26U3/78/. Look at the detailInit function, and you can see how to create your kendoDropDownList on the detail row. You will need to plug in the code to populate that dropdownlist and set the selected value.

Comment: I tried adding the following code for loading the dropdownlist.
 authority.kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: authority.attr("AuthName"),
        dataValueField: authority.attr("AuthId"),
        dataSource: usersViewModel.Authority
    });
But it is not able to get the Authority from the viewmodel.
http://jsfiddle.net/Z26U3/79/

Comment: The issue with your datasource on the dropdown list was that you were specifying the fields and datasource incorrectly. In your example, when assigning the datasource like that, you need to do: `dataSource: new usersViewModel().Authority` since `usersViewModel` is declared as a function. Here is the updated fiddle with the dropdownlist in the detailsview working: http://jsfiddle.net/Z26U3/86/

Comment: Thank you so much for help. Only heads up is the checkbox binding is still not working for detail template.

Comment: To set the checkbox control, you need to inspect the data of the detail row. In `detailInit`, you just need to do this: `detailRow.find(".user-details>input[name=ZwaveLock]").prop('checked', e.data.ZwaveLock);`. I have updated the fiddle with the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Z26U3/92/

Comment: Hello Joe, Here is another issue that I was facing on filters on kendo Grid. Please help if you find time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486507/multiple-filter-on-kendogrid-not-working