# Multiple Filter on kendogrid not working

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown, kendo-datasource

I'm trying to put 2 filters on kendo grid with 'OR' logic.
It's not working. I need the grid to be filtered with the both the dropdowns.
If in Foo dropdown 'foo1' is selected and in Bar dropdown 'All' selected, then the grid should be displaying

```
 foo     bar
  1       1
  1       2
```

Code below:

```
$(function() {  
 var grid=$("#grid").kendoGrid({
 dataSource: {
 data: [
    { foo: "1", bar: "1" },{ foo: "1", bar: "2" },
    { foo: "2", bar: "2" },{ foo: "2", bar: "1" },
    { foo: "3", bar: "3" },{ foo: "3", bar: "2" }
    ]
},
columns: [
  "foo","bar"
],
toolbar: kendo.template($("#template").html())
});
grid.find("#foo").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "name",
        dataValueField: "id",
        autoBind: false,
        optionLabel: "All",
dataSource: [{id:'1', name:'foo1'}, {id:'2', name:'foo2'},{id:'3', name:'foo3'}],
        change: function () {
          var ds = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;        

var filter = {
  logic: "and",
  filters: []
};    
if (this.value()) {
filter.filters.push([{ field: "bar", operator: "eq", value:      
$("#bar").data('kendoDropDownList').value() },
 { field: "foo", operator: "eq", value:  $("#foo").data('kendoDropDownList').value() } 
]);
}
          ds.filter([filter]);
 }
});
grid.find("#bar").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "name",
        dataValueField: "id",
        autoBind: false,
        optionLabel: "All",
dataSource: [{id:'1', name:'bar1'}, {id:'2', name:'bar2'},{id:'3', name:'bar3'}],
        change: function () {
          var ds = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;        

var filter = {
  logic: "and",
  filters: []
};    
if (this.value()) {
filter.filters.push([{ field: "bar", operator: "eq", value:    
$("#bar").data('kendoDropDownList').value() },
 { field: "foo", operator: "eq", value:  $("#foo").data('kendoDropDownList').value() } 
]);
}
          ds.filter([filter]);
}
});
});
After pushing the filters to the filter array the grid datasource is not filtered.
```

Updated jsbin below:
http://jsbin.com/izuloj/23/edit

Comment: I found this example that uses multiple columns for filtering with an OR: http://jsfiddle.net/valchev/MG89G/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple of problems:

- The argument for DataSource `filters` is an array but you are pushing an array when you do:

```
filter.filters.push([
    { field: "bar", operator: "eq", value:  $("#bar").data('kendoDropDownList').value() },
    { field: "foo", operator: "eq", value:  $("#foo").data('kendoDropDownList').value() } 
]);
```

- Comparing with empty is not the same that not adding the condition. So you should actually do:

```
// If there is some value in "bar" we add a condition for filtering it
if ($("#bar").data('kendoDropDownList').value()) {
    filter.filters.push({ 
        field: "bar", 
        operator: "eq", 
        value:  $("#bar").data('kendoDropDownList').value() }
    );
}

// If there is some value in "foo" we add a condition for filtering it
if ($("#foo").data('kendoDropDownList').value()) {
    filter.filters.push(
        { 
            field: "foo", 
            operator: "eq", 
            value:  $("#foo").data('kendoDropDownList').value() } 
    );
}
```

- Finally, you should not set any filter if both drop down inputs are empty but in that case you cannot send an empty filter array, you should do `ds.filter({}))` instead.

So your `change` function ends being:

```
function onChange () {
    var ds = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;        
    var filtering = false;

    var filter = {
        logic: "and",
        filters: []
    };    
    if ($("#bar").data('kendoDropDownList').value()) {
        filtering = true;
        filter.filters.push(
            { field: "bar", operator: "eq", value:  $("#bar").data('kendoDropDownList').value() }
        );
    }
    if ($("#foo").data('kendoDropDownList').value()) {
        filtering = true;
        filter.filters.push(
            { field: "foo", operator: "eq", value:  $("#foo").data('kendoDropDownList').value() } 
        );
    }
    if (filtering) {
        ds.filter([filter]);
    } else {
        ds.filter({});
    }
}
```

Your code modified here : http://jsbin.com/izuloj/31/edit

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
var filter = {
  logic: "and",
  filters: []
};    
if (this.value()) {
filter.filters.push([{ field: "bar", operator: "eq", value:    
$("#bar").data('kendoDropDownList').value() },
 { field: "foo", operator: "eq", value:  $("#foo").data('kendoDropDownList').value() } 
]);
}
          ds.filter([filter]);
```

Doing below works....easy to read

```
     if ( $("#foo").data('kendoDropDownList').value() === "")
          {
            ds.filter( { field: "bar", operator: "eq", value: $("#bar").data('kendoDropDownList').value()});
          }
          else
          {

          ds.filter({
                  logic: "and",
                  filters: [{ field: "foo", operator: "eq", value: $("#foo").data('kendoDropDownList').value() },{ field: "bar", operator: "eq", value: $("#bar").data('kendoDropDownList').value()  }]
          });
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the square brackets on `ds.filter([filter]);` so that it becomes  `ds.filter(filter);`.